# How correctly to set up autocomplete_fields in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django

Trying to set up autocomplete_fields for ForeingKey in Django admin. I don't understand how correctly to set it up. I read the docs but there is not much information about autocomplete_fields, not enough for me at least.

**admin.py**

```
class AdminSettings(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('english_word', 'russian_word', 'turkish_word')
    list_display = ['circassian_word', 'letter']
    autocomplete_fields = ('circassian_word',)
    search_fields = ['circassian_word__circassian']
```

**models.py**

```
class Word(models.Model):
    circassian_word = models.ForeignKey(Circassian, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Адыгэбзэ')
    letter = models.ForeignKey(Alphabet, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Буква')
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio', blank=True, verbose_name='Озвучка')
    turkish_word = models.ManyToManyField(Turkish, blank=True, verbose_name='Türkçe')
    english_word = models.ManyToManyField(English, blank=True, verbose_name='English')
    russian_word = models.ManyToManyField(Russian, blank=True, verbose_name='Русский')
```

**Error message**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10d07b9d8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 410, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'psalale.admin.AdminSettings'>: (admin.E037) The value of 'autocomplete_fields[0]' refers to 'circassian_word__circassian', which is not an attribute of 'psalale.Word'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it said in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields):

> You must define `search_fields` on the related object’s `ModelAdmin` because the autocomplete search uses it.

So you need to define

```
class CircassianAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = []  # <- list of keys to search by
```

register it via decorator `@admin.register(Circassian)` or via `admin.site.register(CircassianAdmin)`

and remove `search_fields` attribute from `AdminSettings`

*Friendly suggestion:* rename `AdminSettings` to smth like `WordAdmin`, it is much more readable.

Comment: you mean `admin.site.register(CircassianADMIN)`?

Comment: @Bootuz oh, yeah, sorry. Fixed that.

Comment: ok, I've done that, but get this error `TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable`

Comment: I really don't understand how to set up this... I tried all compossible combinations of `search_fields` and `autocomplete_fields `...

Comment: @Bootuz can you, please, post related models in `models.py` and related `ModelAdmin` classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161942/discussion-between-vishes-shell-and-bootuz).

Comment: What does **autocomplete_fields** do?